# how to ignore multiple entries with same index while reading data from CSV using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
patient_id, age_in_years,   CENSUS_REGION,  URBAN_RURAL_STATUS, YEAR

11511,  7,  Northeast,  Urban,  2011

9882613,    73, South,  Urban,  2011

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,  2011

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,  2011

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,  2011

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,  2011

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,  2011

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,  2011
...
```

The first column (i.e., patient_id) is the index and you can see that there are multiple entries for the same patient. I want my code to ignore these multiple entries when I import the data using `pandas` but I'm not sure how to do that. I'm using the following code for this purpose at the moment:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = 0)
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Further on in the code I have a function that says:

```
def URSTATUS_to_numeric(a):
if a == 'Urban':
    return 0
if a == 'Rural':
    return 1
if a == 'NULL':
    return 2
```

When I call this function and print it using `df.drop_duplicates()` though, this is what I get:

```
df['URSTATUS_num'] = df['URBAN_RURAL_STATUS'].apply(URSTATUS_to_numeric)

print(df.drop_duplicates(['URSTATUS_num']))

>>> patient_id  URSTATUS_num  
     11511            0  
     129126475        1  
     151269094        NaN
```

So basically it is dropping the duplicates considering the `URSTATUS_num` column as the reference. However, I want the code to always reference `patient_id` while performing the `drop_duplicates()` operation. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can ignore them as they are being read, but once they have been read you can easily drop them using `drop_duplicates`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = 0)
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
   patient_id  age_in_years CENSUS_REGION URBAN_RURAL_STATUS  YEAR
0       11511             7     Northeast              Urban  2011
1     9882613            73         South              Urban  2011
2    32190339            49          West              Urban  2011
```

EDIT:

You probably just want to call it once, e.g.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = 0).drop_duplicates()
```

Depending on the cleanliness of your underlying data, you may first need to pre-process to strip spaces, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes things much easier since I'm dropping multiple entries even before pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `drop_duplcates` "in place" with

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Then same convention applies with other dataframe methods such as `sort`, `fill_na`, and so on. I guess it's a matter of personal taste whether you use this syntax, or the more "functional"

```
df_dedup = df.drop_duplicates()
```

although the default behavior (`inplace=False`) does tend to be the one that I ususally use.